# How do we write a function that merges two lists together?

Tags: list, merge, racket

The question I am trying to answer is:
write a function (within Dr.Racket/Scheme) called merge that produces a list of toys from two lists of toys (toys1 and toys2). This produced list will have alternating toys from toys1 and toys2 with the first value coming from toys1. Also, if the nth toy in toys1 and toys2 is the same toy (color and type), then the list produced should only contain one toy structure (e.g. not replicated) with that color and type. If the lists are of different lengths, then the last k toy in the list will be the last k toy from the longer list.

Use the following structure to complete this question:

```
(define-struct toy (color type))
;; A Toy is a (make-toy Str Str)
```

An example for this program would be:

```
(merge (list (make-toy "blue" "ball") (make-toy "blue" "spring") 
   (make-toy "red" "helmet") (make-toy "purple" "band"))
   (list (make-toy "yellow" "van") (make-toy "blue" "spring")))
```

produces

```
(list (make-toy "blue" "ball") (make-toy "yellow" "van")
  (make-toy "blue" "spring") (make-toy "red" "helmet")
  (make-toy "purple" "band"))
```

Now, the program I have created so far is the following:

```
(define (merge toys1 toys2)
  (cond
     [(empty? toys1) toys2]
     [(empty? toys2) toys1]
     [else
         (first toys1) (first toys2)
         (merge (rest toys1) (rest toys2))]))
```

Now the problem I am having is that I don't know how I will incorporate the condition about deleting the repeats in the final list produced.
Any advice will me mighty helpful!

Comment: Sorry but this looks like a homework request, and that's not StackOverflow is for. Please try and solve that yourself, and if you run into trouble, then you can ask for help with solving the problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Actually, homework is OK, [but](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) you should attempt to solve the problem yourself first and then ask about your existing implementation.

Comment: (read on if you've actually thought about the solution and are stuck): check: if both are non empty, put the first element of each list in your accumulator, recurse with `(rest lst1)` and `(rest lst2)` else put the nonempty one at the end of your accumulator and finish.

Are you by any chance taking CS115/CS135 at UW?

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for your input! I have recently edited my question adding on to the code I have been currently working on. Any advice would be great!!

Comment: And nope, I am not taking any CS courses at waterloo. I am trying to practice some coding on my own so I can write down that I have experience with Dr.Racket. My friends gave me a textbook, and from there is where I found this question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are two ways to get rid of repetition:

1. **While you're building the list, you make sure you aren't putting in repeating values**. If you do this, what will happen is, by not inserting the value that is repeated where it should be and inserting the next value in the list, you mess up the order in which you  interleave the two lists. But at the same time, you are also ensuring that you get a proper alternating list.
2. **After you have already built the list, go through it and remove duplicates.** This can be done by calling your current function `merge-help` and then creating a function `merge` that removes duplicates from the list produced by `merge-help`. Doing it this way will be easier to implement, but there's no guarantee your list will meet the requirements, i.e., it may not be correctly interleaved.

Solution 1 is definitely more tedious but it will give you better results. My suggestion would be to first remove duplicates from either list in a function called `remove-dups` or something of that nature. Then on the newly changed lists, implement your current `merge`, which seems like it will work, if you follow [soegaard's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23567/soegaard) advice.